# Manage versions of local dependencies in Maven Tycho multi module project

Tags: maven, osgi, tycho

I have a PDE multi-module project. This project is built with Maven (it uses Tycho). Each module dependencies are described in OSGI-style manifests, so the modules are in manifest-first style.

Some modules depend on other local modules, so I have the following in manifests:

```
Bundle-SymbolicName: com.example.module1;singleton:=true
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0
Require-Bundle: com.example.module2;bundle-version="[1.0.0]",
com.example.module3;bundle-version="[1.0.0]",
```

The bundle version and versions of local dependencies are the same. I cannot remove versions of local dependencies from manifests and I cannot generate manifests from maven (tycho, which validates manifests, runs in the beginning of maven lifecycle).

In order to update project version I have to use "tycho-versions" maven plugin. It updates version number in poms, eclipse features and manifests. But versions of local dependencies are not updated (for obvious reasons). This issue is fixed by my custom script.

Questions:

- Is there a way to manage versions of local dependencies in OSGI manifests?
- Are there any best practices to manage versions of local dependencies in multi module OSGI (manifest-first) projects?

Comment: It is not 100% clear what exactly you want to archive. Do you want to enforce that your module1 only runs with module2 with exactly the same version? This is not what you currently specify: `bundle-version="1.0.0"` means "version 1.0.0 or greater".

Comment: @oberlies, thank you for your comment. I've fixed my question.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that Eclipse projects traditionally apply to this problem is to have a feature that includes the plug-ins from the project, and in that way ensure that only versions from the same build are installed together.

This obviously only works if the feature, which ties together the versions, is also installed. Features are typically used for plug-in functionality that is installed by Eclipse users. If you are building a library which is only used by other Eclipse plug-ins, your plug-in may also be installed without a feature.

In the latter case, you probably would need to extend the Tycho versions plugin to also automatically update the dependencies with strict version range dependencies, like `bundle-version="[1.0.0]"`